# How to parse XML nested value for multiple child group

Tags: python, xml, pandas, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have big `.xml` file that part of it is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <measData>
        <Mesurment Id="55">
            <granPeriod duration="1" endTime="2021-01-02"/>
            <repPeriod duration="1"/>
            <measTypes>73 74 574 75 35 36 </measTypes>
            <measValue measObj="Group1">
                <measResults>512 52.733 33.5 82 0 0 </measResults>
            </measValue>
            <measValue measObj="Group2">
                <measResults>512 78.175 50 119.5 0 0 </measResults>
            </measValue>
        </Mesurment>
    </measData>
</data>
```

I'm trying to pars required data out of it and csv it in CSV file.
the problem I have is that in xml file `<measTypes>` is repeated once and values for this `<measTypes>` for group1 and Group2 mentioned afterward.
for different `<Mesurment Id>` it is vary and might be more than 10 group value reported for each`<measTypes>`
The problem is here that I don't know how to report multiple `measResults` for one `measTypes`
I have following code to fetch values:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
parsDict = dict()
tree = ET.parse('new.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for itm in tree.iter():
    if (itm.tag.split('}')[-1] == 'Mesurment'):
        parsDict['Mesurment'] = [itm.attrib['Id']]
    if (itm.tag.split('}')[-1] == 'granPeriod'):
        parsDict['duration'] = [itm.attrib['duration']]
        parsDict['endTime'] = [itm.attrib['endTime']]
    if (itm.tag.split('}')[-1] == 'measTypes'):
        parsDict['CounterID'] = [itm.text]
    if (itm.tag.split('}')[-1] == 'measValue'):
        parsDict['measObj'] = [itm.attrib['measObj']]
    if (itm.tag.split('}')[-1] == 'measResults'):
        parsDict['value'] = [itm.text]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(parsDict)
df2.to_csv('123.csv',index=False)
print('finish')
```

The result is like below

[image]

which is reporting the latest group
my desire result is llike below which need to be capable to extend for multiple group and measurement Id

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to do that using `BeautifulSoup` library. Before using it you should install these dependencies:

```
beautifulsoup4 = "4.9.3"
lxml = "^4.6.1"
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <measData>
        <Mesurment Id="55">
            <granPeriod duration="1" endTime="2021-01-02"/>
            <repPeriod duration="1"/>
            <measTypes>73 74 574 75 35 36 </measTypes>
            <measValue measObj="Group1">
                <measResults>512 52.733 33.5 82 0 0 </measResults>
            </measValue>
            <measValue measObj="Group2">
                <measResults>512 78.175 50 119.5 0 0 </measResults>
            </measValue>
        </Mesurment>
    </measData>
</data>
""", features="xml")

response = []

for tag in soup.data.measData:
    if not isinstance(tag, Tag):
        continue
    
    # please, update this dict with all the top level attributes you need
    data = {"duration": tag.granPeriod.attrs["duration"], }

    for measValue in tag:
        if not isinstance(measValue, Tag) or getattr(measValue, "measResults") is None:
            continue

        response.append({
            **data,
            "measObj": measValue.attrs["measObj"],
            "value": measValue.measResults.text
        })

print(response)
```

**UPDATE**

Using the library you do, it can be done like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse('new.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

response = []

for mesurment in tree.iter("Mesurment"):
    granPeriod = next(
        it for it in mesurment if it.tag == "granPeriod"
    )
    measTypes = next(
        it for it in mesurment if it.tag == "measTypes"
    )
    measValues = [it for it in mesurment if it.tag == "measValue"]

    mesurment_data = {
        "Mesurment": mesurment.attrib["Id"],
        "duration": granPeriod.attrib["duration"],
        "endTime": granPeriod.attrib["endTime"],
        "CounterId": measTypes.text,
    }

    for value in measValues:
        response.append({
            **mesurment_data,
            "measObj": value.attrib["measObj"],
            "value": next(
                it.text for it in value if it.tag == "measResults"
            )
        })

df2 = pd.DataFrame(response)
print(df2)
```

Comment: I prefer not to add another package to my code, Also speed for parsing in another concern

Comment: @Mohsen I updated my answer, this should suffice

Comment: Thanks, it work perfectly on extended data,but i have issue with my original file and the error is : 
`it for it in mesurment if it.tag == "granPeriod"
StopIteration`

Comment: @Mohsen
It may happen if a tag does not exist for a specific mesurment. In this case just convert all the `next` statements to this format `next((it for it in mesurment if it.tag == "granPeriod"), None)`. So if it does not find any tag, it returns a None. Then you'll have an if statement to check if it exists so it does not fail on this line `granPeriod.attrib["duration"]`